# How to change default JRE for all Eclipse workspaces?

Tags: eclipse, java

I have one JRE in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6` and that was the only one at the time I installed Eclipse.  I have subsequently installed a complete JDK in `C:\home\SFTWR\jdk1.6.0_21` and changed my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to that.  However, every time I start a new Eclipse workspace, it only picks up the old JRE and I have to manually remove it and add the new one.

How do I bind my Eclipse install to the new JDK so that every new workspace points to that only?  I checked `eclipse.ini` but there was no reference there to which JRE to go to.

**UPDATE:**

I went into `Prefs->Java->Installed JRE`s, added the new location, marked it as default, removed the other, and it was effective only for the current workspace. However, when I opened a new workspace, only the old JRE was available.  So this didn't change the core Eclipse config that is applicable across all (at least new) workspaces

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally got it:  **The way Eclipse picks up the JRE is using the system's PATH**.

I did not have `C:\home\SFTWR\jdk1.6.0_21\bin` in the path at all before and I did have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin`.  I had both `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` set to `C:\home\SFTWR\jdk1.6.0_21` but neither of those two mattered.  I guess Eclipse did (something to the effect of) **where java** (or **which** on UNIX/Linux) to see where Java is in the path and took the JRE to which that `java.exe` belonged.  In my case, despite all the configuration tweaks I had done (including `eclipse.ini` -vm option as suggested above), it remained stuck to what was in the path.

I removed the old JRE bin from the path, put the new one in, and it works for all workspaces.

Comment: Don't forget to pick up your [Sock Puppet](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet) - though finding your head to place it on may be difficult. ;-)

Comment: I wonder if the eclipse team will ever make eclipse even remotely user friendly. FFS.... this literally worked fine yesterday, and today without warning just decided I had not spent enough of the work day servicing eclipse. Thanks for this... spared me from having to reinstall java for the umpteenth time to appease eclipse. Next time ill just sacrifice a lamb or something ahead of time.

Comment: `The way Eclipse picks up the JRE is using the system's PATH` wrong. I have no single mention about Java in my `PATH` but Eclipse anyway picks Java 11 for some reason instead, disregard only Java 8 is added in installed JREs setting in preferences.

Answer (score 16):

> Open the   Java > Installed JREs preference page. Check the box on the
>   line for the JRE that you want to assign as the default JRE in your
>   workbench. If the JRE you want to assign as the default does not
>   appear in the list, you must add it. Click OK.

Source-http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-assign_default_jre.htm

Comment: this didn't work either.  I went into `Prefs->Java->Installed JREs`, added the new location, marked it as default, removed the other, and it was effective only for the current workspace.  when i opened a new workspace, only the old JRE was available

Comment: yes, i created a whole new workspace, changed the JRE, closed it.  then opened yet another new workspace hoping that the previous JRE change would take effect but it didn't as i only had the old JRE

Comment: `it was effective only for the current workspace` moreover, for me it wasn't effective even for that workspace. I have only **one** JRE listed in preferences, but Eclipse use another anyway

Answer (score 16):

The Installed JREs is used for what JREs to execute for your downstream Java projects and servers.  As far as what JVM or JRE that is used to execute Eclipse process (workbench) itself that is controlled by your environment, history and eclipse.exe binary.  So eclipse.exe itself decides what JRE Eclipse will execute itself with, not installed JREs preferences since those are not read until OSGi framework is up and running which is loaded after the JVM/JRE is picked.

So for new workspaces, Eclipse is going to use its currently executing JRE to populate the JRE prefs.

The best way I know how is to force eclipse.exe to use the JRE that you tell it via the `-vm` switch.  So in your eclipse.ini do this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-vm
/path/to/exactly/what/jre/you/want/as/default/javaw.exe
...
```

Comment: this didn't work.  I added `-vm
C:\home\SFTWR\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: Did you put the -vm on a separate line as the path?  it should look like
-vm
C:/home/...

Comment: it worked for me  just added --vm                                                         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\javaw.exe     in eclipse configuration file

Comment: This Fixed my problem - The eclipse.ini had the old version java hard-coded with "-vm" . Once I removed the "-vm \path\to\non-existent\java" line, it picked up the new version no problem.

Answer (score 15):

In eclipse go to

**Window-> Java -> Installed JREs**

You can remove your current installed jre and add the jdk by specifying the path to where the jdk is installed.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My answer will overlap with amphibient's while adding on to it.

Your JAVA_HOME variable is fine, but you also need to append the following to your Path variable :

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

This will allow your applications in your Windows environment to access your JDK. You should also restart your computer once you've added these environment variables before checking out if they work. In my case, even logging out and then back in didn't work : I had to completely restart.

If you want to check if the environment variables are set correctly, you can open up a command prompt and type >`echo %JAVA_HOME` and >`echo %Path%` to see if those variables are working correctly. While snooping around for solutions, I have also run into people claiming that they need to add quotations marks (") around the environment variables to make them work correctly (`"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin`) if your JAVA_HOME path includes spaces. I thought that this was my case at first, but after doing a full restart my variables seemed to work correctly without quotation marks despite the spaces.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue where eclipse was not using my current `%JAVA_HOME%` that was on the `path` and was instead using an older version.  The documentation points out that if no `-vm` is specified in the ini file, eclipse will search for a shared library `jvm.dll`  This appears in the registry under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` that gets installed when using the windows java installer (key might be a bit different based on 64-bit vs 32-bit, but search for `jvm.dll`).  Because it was finding this shared library on my `path` before the `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`, it was using the old version.

Like others have stated, the easiest way to deal with this is to specify the specific vm you want to use in the `eclipse.ini` file.  I'm writing this because I couldn't figure out how it was still using the old version when it wasn't specified anywhere on the `path` or `eclipse.ini` file.

See link to doc below:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html?cp=2_1_3_1

> **Finding a VM and using the JNI Invocation API**
>
> The Eclipse launcher is capable of loading the Java VM in the eclipse process using the Java Native Interface Invocation API.  The launcher is still capable of starting the Java VM in a separate process the same as previous version of Eclipse did.  Which method is used depends on how the VM was found.
>
> **No -vm specified**
>
> When no -vm is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine first in a jre directory in the root of eclipse and then on the search path. If java is found in either location, then the launcher looks for a jvm shared library (jvm.dll on Windows, libjvm.so on *nix platforms) relative to that java executable.
>
> - If a jvm shared library is found the launcher loads it and uses the JNI invocation API to start the vm.
> - If no jvm shared library is found, the launcher executes the java launcher to start the vm in a new process.
>
> **-vm specified on the command line or in eclipse.ini**
>
> Eclipse can be started with "-vm " to indicate a virtual machine to use. There are several possibilities for the value of :
>
> - **directory:**   is a directory. We look in that directory for:
>
>   - (1) a java launcher or
>   - (2) the jvm shared library.
>
> If we find the jvm shared library, we use JNI invocation. If we find a launcher, we attempt to find a jvm library in known locations relative to the launcher. If we find one, we use JNI invocation. If no jvm library is found, we exec java in a new process.
>
> - **java.exe/javaw.exe:**  is a path to a java launcher. We exec that java launcher to start the vm in a new process.
> - **jvm dll or so:**  is a path to a jvm shared library. We attempt to load that library and use the JNI Invocation API to start the vm in the current process.

Answer (score 4):

when you select run configuration, there is a JRE tap up next the main tap, select "**Workspace default JRE(JDK1.7)**".

Be sure to use the jdk in `Prefs->Java->Installed JREs ->Execution Environment`

Answer (score 3):

I have faced with the same issue. The resolve:
- Window-->Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs-->Add...
- Right click on your project-->Build Path-->Configure Build Path-->Add library-->JRE system library-->next-->WorkSpace Default JRE

Answer (score 0):

try to change the order: 
right click on you project-> BuildPath->Configure...->Order and Export tab -> move jre7 UP.

Answer (score 0):

I navigated to:

```
Eclipse>Pref>Java>Installed JRE>Search...
```

2 of them popped up and I checked the latest one.  Before I did this I also went to `About>Check for Updates` and updated it. I didn't have to reinstall any JRE or JDK either. I might have done it a while back, except it was with 1.6 not 1.4. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

On windows I've tried different approaches 
- setting JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and extending the PATH to point to the desiered jre18 but nothing helped 
- disabling the JRE17 in the java control panel didn't helped either

What helped me out was to force eclipse to use the appropriate JRE in the eclipse.ini file e.g.

-vm
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan Michev answer also worked for me,

edit eclispe.ini to point to your installed JRE
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1-openj\bin

but to elaborate;
My application server uses JAVA_HOME and thus PATH so I needed Eclipse to pick up another JRE to run (so to be compatible with an installed plugin).

This Eclipse JRE is different than
than setting Window-> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs which as you see in the below image, is for building Java projects, so you can have different projects with different JDKs

[Eclipse Installed JREs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IURz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I ran into a similar problem with eclipse epsilon. It was installed with the Oomph Installer, that allows to select a JDK.

To change the JDK that the workspace/installation uses, I had to edit the `eclipse\epsilon-2-4\eclipse\eclipse.ini`.

This change was nessesary since the current versions of Java do not allow nasty Reflection accesses to internal classes :).

The `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME`, *wasn't* event set and adding/changing it also did not help.