# How do set all Eclipse projects to same JVM at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I am working on a large project with about 60 different Eclipse projects. I am looking for a method of setting the JVM for all projects at once. I know that I can right click on each one, go to Build Path, and manually change it to a certain execution environment (or JVM or workspace default), but it appears that this must be done one at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099530/how-to-change-default-jre-for-all-eclipse-workspaces)

Comment: I have seen this. However, this deals with a workspace, which, in Eclipse, is different from a project. I have many projects that reference JDK1 and many others that reference JDK2 (names are the important item here). However, my JDK is named JDK3. I want to simply set all JDKs to JDK3. Another option is to set them all to a specific runtime-environment, which is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do it via the UI, but you could use a File search+replace to modify the `.classpath` files directly.

From the menu, toolbar, or keyboard shortcut open the **File Search** dialog. The text you want to search for, assuming your projects all use Execution Environment to specify their JRE libraries, is something like `StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7` (that's the text for the **JavaSE-1.7** Execution Environment). Specify `.classpath` as the file name pattern, and the **Scope** you want, then click **Replace...**

[image]

In the **Replace Text Matches** dialog, specify the new Execution Environment text, for example `StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8`. **OK** or **Preview>** to continue with the replacement.

[image]

Eclipse will re-build all the projects and once it completes they should all be referencing the new Execution Environment.

Comment: This is what I did. I guess I was just curious if Eclipse provided a solution.