# Eclipse wont start after updating Java version

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have updated to the latest version of Java, but when I try opening Eclipse I get the following error messages

[image]

[image]

My **JDK** version is: **1.8.0_45**

My **JRE** version is: **1.8.0_73**

I have tried some of the suggestions I found such as:

- removing the default installation copies java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to C:\Windows\System32 (which I didnt have)
- removing the previous version of Java JRE: **1.8.0_65**
- update the **eclipse.ini** file, which is as follows

[image]

but I still have no luck.

Even when I move the highlighted text above **vmargs**, I get ANOTHER error

[image]
How can I fix these errors?

Comment: in eclipse.ini change ine line -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

Comment: @AjayPandya still no luck after trying that

Comment: Do you notice the strange character in the path in the last error screenshot? Perhaps your hyphen character is some other Unicode character?

Comment: This helped my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099530/how-to-change-default-jre-for-all-eclipse-workspaces

Answer (score 0):

Use `-vm` above `-vmargs` because all the parameter below `-vmagrs` is for JVM.
See below image:

[image]

**Try this**

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Comment: I have tried that also, as I mentioned, and I get another error (the last image)

Comment: @swagantiswag Can you try the above code and please add that live above `-vmargs`

Comment: Thanks, I updated that too, but no luck either. I found a solution however, which is now posted.